# REST API returning NotFound (404) if record is not found in the database

Tags: c#, error-handling

I'm not really sure what the preferred way is to deal with records not found in the database. Is it better to write a `Find` method which returns `null` or a `Get` method which raises a `RecordNotFoundException`?

```
[AuthenticateFilter(UsernameAndSecretKey)]
[Route("api/v1/activities/emails/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetEmailActivity(int id)
{
  try
  {
    // business logic service, could use only db service but this way we can do unit tests (just fill bl service method with fake objects)
    var service = new EmailActivityBlService();

    // 1. use Find method which returns null in case record with provided id does not exist in db
    var model = service.FindActivity(id);
    if( model != null )
      return Ok(model);
    return NotFound();  

   // 2. or is this approach better
   // throws RecordNotFoundException in case row by id is not found in database
   return Ok(service.GetActivity(id));
  }
  catch(RecordNotFoundException e) { return NotFound(); }
  catch(Exception e) { return InternalServerError(e); }
}
```

`EmailActivityBlService` has next code in case anyone interested (showing only the important part):

```
private EmailActivityDbService _dbService;

public EmailActivityModel GetActivity(int id)
{
  var model = this._dbService.GetActivity(id);
  if( model == null )
    throw new RecordNotFoundException(); // I suppose System.Data.ObjectNotFound is also suitable
  return model;
}

public EmailActivityModel FindActivity(int id)
{
  // typical entity framework query
  // using(var context = new ..) { return contect.EmailActivity.Where()..SingleOrDefault().ConvertToModel();
  return this._dbService.GetActivity(id);
}
```

Comment: Is this an unintended error that you're getting?

Comment: No intended of course. This is correct behaviour. Api has to return 404 if resource is not found, just not sure which code is better - Find returning null or Get throwing exception.

Comment: I need to make sure because if this code is broken, it's off-topic.

Comment: I see. The code works as it should. Well, I could change the title so it would say "it doesn't work'.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview; that's a good first question, enjoy your stay!